# Sequential Api calls for multiple urls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a stock web app as a project for my bootcamp course and was trying to run async api calls sequentially in a loop. I understand that I'm using a forEach loop where I probably should be using .reduce and there are plenty of examples that show how to use reduce out of context but as I'm new to javascript, I can't seem to make the connection between the conceptual explanations of using .reduce for multiple promises and practically applying it in my example.

I had initially made individual fetches and .thens for each url and realised pretty quickly that I needed to refactor it in a loop of some sort. The problem I'm running into is that the order of the array that i push the data into is randomised because the promises are resolved asynchronously. Further along in my app I'm using the pulled data to draw charts with Chart.js, so i need my data in a specific order otherwise the data for the google share price gets drawn on the apple graph.

The apple, google, tesla, brka, fb are variables where the fetch is stored. I haven't written those in because I have an api key in the url.

Anyways, below is my code. Your help is much appreciated.

```
Promise.all([apple, google, tesla, brka, fb])
    .then((arrOfRes) => {
      arrOfRes.forEach((response) => {
        pushStockObjects(response.json())
      });
    });

// function that pushes object into array
const pushStockObjects = (json) => {
    json.then((data) => {
    let package = [];
    let daily = [];
    let timeSeriesArr = [];
    let symbolSignifier = [];
    let test = (data["Time Series (Daily)"]);
    const entries = Object.entries(test)
    for(let i = 0; i < 17; i ++) {
      daily.push(entries[i][1]["4. close"]);
      timeSeriesArr.push(entries[i][0]);
      symbolSignifier.push(data["Meta Data"]["2. Symbol"])
    }
    package.push(daily.reverse());
    package.push(timeSeriesArr.reverse());
    package.push(symbolSignifier);
    arrayOfDailyAndTimeArr.push(package); 
    console.log(arrayOfDailyAndTimeArr)
    drawChart(arrayOfDailyAndTimeArr[0][1], arrayOfDailyAndTimeArr[0][0], 'rgba(196, 117, 246, 0.6)', 
              'rgb(196, 117, 246)', 'rgb(234, 241, 242)', 'Apple')
  });
};
```

Comment: The problem is related to resolve the promise in a specific order so you will have data in the same order?

Comment: this: _because the promises are resolved asynchronously_ is the classic problem of data structure selection. Using a **list** that does not guarantee order vs. using a **hash** (key/value) pair in which order does not matter. You cannot control the order, so you must control the structure.

Comment: Best piece of advice ever! Thanks Randy! And thank you Garry for responding.